# Terraform - Custom Api Gateway module with map variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I created a terraform module for AWS Api Gateway.
As an API Gateway can have multiples resources, methods, integrations, etc, I've created maps variable.
I have a map for each elements.

I linked the map together using the map keys.

```
variable "map_resources" {
  description = "Description for resources"
  default = {}
  type = map(object({
    path_part = string,
    parent_id = string,
    level = number
  }))
}

variable "map_methods" {
  description = "Description for methods"
  default = {}
  type = map(object({
    http_method = string,
    authorization = string,
    authorizer_id = string,
    resource_map_name = string
  }))
}

variable "map_method_response" {
  description = "Description for method response"
  default = {}
  type = map(object({
    statusCode = string,
    resource_map_name = string,
    method_map_name = string
  }))
}

variable "map_integrations" {
  description = "Description for integrations"
  default = {}
  type = map(object({
    integration_http_method = string,
    type = string,
    uri = string,
    integration_timeout = string,
    resource_map_name = string,
    method_map_name = string
  }))
}
```

The first use of the module work fine. However anytime, I had a new resource (with method, integration, ...) Terraform tries to redeploy all the API Gateway, as if it didn't know the existing one.

I check the tfstate and everything is fine it.

In the plan step, I can see that terraform doesn't recognize the ID of the resource for the methods and integrations.

```
# module.privateApiGateway.aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod["document_metadata_method"] must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxyMethod" {
      - authorization_scopes = [] -> null
      ~ id                   = "agm-fziy54uz69-7xa9au-ANY" -> (known after apply)
      - request_models       = {} -> null
      ~ resource_id          = "7xa9au" # forces replacement -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
```

Then in the apply step, Terraform tries to recreate the existing resources...

> Error: creating API Gateway Method: ConflictException: Method already exists for this resource
> │
> │   with module.privateApiGateway.aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod["document_metadata_method"],
> │   on .terraform/modules/privateApiGateway/method.tf line 1, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxyMethod":
> │    1: resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxyMethod" {

My guessing is that on the plan step, Terraform can't evaluate the map values. Do you have any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question.